# Keyframe animate absolute positioned buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have one large button at z-index: 1, covering up two smaller buttons at z-indices 0.9 and 0.8, respectively. On click of the first button, they should slide out. This only occurs when they do not have the "position: absolute;" property, however this causes them to be placed lower on the screen, rather than beneath the element that's meant to be covering them.

Link to CodePen
https://codepen.io/Gladdstone/pen/aYObGy

```js
function setConversion(obj) {
  if($(obj).hasClass("buttonpress")) {
      $(obj).removeClass("buttonpress");

      // add "in" animation classes
      $("#celsius").addClass("celsius-in");
      $("#fahrenheit").addClass("fahrenheit-in");

      // remove "out" animation classes
      if($("#celsius").hasClass("celsius-out")) {
          $("#celsius").removeClass("celsius-out");
          $("#fahrenheit").removeClass("fahrenheit-out");
      }
  } else {
      $(obj).addClass("buttonpress");

      // add "out" animation classes
      $("#celsius").addClass("celsius-out");
      $("#fahrenheit").addClass("fahrenheit-out");

      // remove "in" animation classes
      if($("#celsius").hasClass("celsius-in")) {
          $("#celsius").removeClass("celsius-in");
          $("#fahrenheit").removeClass("fahrenheit-in");
      }
  }
}
```

```css
.celsius-in {
    animation-name: celsius-in;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.celsius-out {
    animation-name: celsius-out;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.fahrenheit-in {
    animation-name: fahrenheit-in;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.fahrenheit-out {
    animation-name: fahrenheit-out;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.overmap {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

.temp-small {
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-color: #007aff;
    background-color: #007aff;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px #888888;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 75%;
    height: 10vw;
    width: 10vw;
    transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#celsius {
    z-index: 0.8;
}

#fahrenheit {
    z-index: 0.9;
}

#temp {
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-color: #007aff;
    background-color: #007aff;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px #888888;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-right: 10%;
    margin-left: 75%;
    height: 20vw;
    width: 20vw;
    transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#tempbutton {
    bottom: 10%;
    width: 100%;
}

@keyframes celsius-out {
    from { margin-left: 75%; }
    to { margin-left: 30%; }
}

@keyframes celsius-in {
    from { margin-left: 30%; }
    to { margin-left: 75%; }
}

@keyframes fahrenheit-out {
    from { margin-left: 75%; }
    to { margin-left: 50%; }
}

@keyframes fahrenheit-in {
    from { margin-left: 50%; }
    to { margin-left: 75%; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tempbutton" class="overmap">
     <button id="temp" type="button" onclick="setConversion(this);">78&deg;</button>
     <button id="fahrenheit" type="button" class="temp-small">&deg;F</button>
     <button id="celsius" type="button" class="temp-small">&deg;C</button>  
</div>
```

Comment: Can you give more details about what you exactly want and in which direction two smaller button should slide. do you want to keep two smaller button hidden under the large button?

Comment: Yeah, sure. Basically think your typical mobile app animation. In the context of the display, the larger button sits in the bottom right corner, and when tapped, the two smaller buttons should slide out (to the left) from underneath it. My problem is that this slide animation only occurs when they are not absolutely positioned.

Comment: @Gladdstone Why do they need to be absolutely positioned? Shouldn't it be alright to wrap them in a element and absolutely position that element. With that you shouldn't need to absolutely position the elements with the slide animation.

Comment: The div they are in is absolutely positioned, but from what I've seen, unless the buttons themselves are positioned absolutely, they sit vertically rather than on top of each other.

Comment: @Gladdstone Sorry for the wait. That is likely related to elements wrapping or the display property. You will either need to work the with width, height and display properties of your elements or possible use flexbox. It's getting late so I can't post a full answer right now.

Comment: I hadn’t considered flexbox. I’ll certainly try those things in the morning. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is this you want ??**

```js
function setConversion(obj) {
  if($(obj).hasClass("buttonpress")) {
      $(obj).removeClass("buttonpress");

      // add "in" animation classes
      $("#celsius").addClass("celsius-in");
      $("#fahrenheit").addClass("fahrenheit-in");

      // remove "out" animation classes
      if($("#celsius").hasClass("celsius-out")) {
          $("#celsius").removeClass("celsius-out");
          $("#fahrenheit").removeClass("fahrenheit-out");
      }
  } else {
      $(obj).addClass("buttonpress");

      // add "out" animation classes
      $("#celsius").addClass("celsius-out");
      $("#fahrenheit").addClass("fahrenheit-out");

      // remove "in" animation classes
      if($("#celsius").hasClass("celsius-in")) {
          $("#celsius").removeClass("celsius-in");
          $("#fahrenheit").removeClass("fahrenheit-in");
      }
  }
}
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

.celsius-in {
    animation-name: celsius-in;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.celsius-out {
    animation-name: celsius-out;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.fahrenheit-in {
    animation-name: fahrenheit-in;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.fahrenheit-out {
    animation-name: fahrenheit-out;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.overmap {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
.temp-small {
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-color: #007aff;
    background-color: #007aff;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px #888888;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 10vw;
    width: 10vw;
    transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease-in-out;
    right: 60px;
    top: 45px;
}
#temp {
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-color: #007aff;
    background-color: #007aff;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px #888888;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-right: 10%;
    margin-left: 75%;
    height: 20vw;
    width: 20vw;
    transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 5;
}
#tempbutton {
    bottom: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

@keyframes celsius-out {
    from { right: 40px; }
    to { right: 50%; }
}

@keyframes celsius-in {
    from { right: 50%; }
    to { right: 40px; }
}

@keyframes fahrenheit-out {
    from { right: 40px; }
    to { right: 70%; }
}

@keyframes fahrenheit-in {
    from { right: 70%; }
    to {right: 40px;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tempbutton" class="overmap">
     <button id="temp" type="button" onclick="setConversion(this);">78&deg;</button>
     <button id="fahrenheit" type="button" class="temp-small">&deg;F</button>
     <button id="celsius" type="button" class="temp-small">&deg;C</button>  
</div>
```

Comment: This helped me a lot, thank you very much. Looking over this, I see the issue I was having was absolutely positioning the larger button. By having the div parent absolute, the large button relative, and the small ones absolute, they can overlay. Thank you!